# why the testvar ??= "default"; still yield testvar is not defined?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, es6-modules

I have something in my html:

```
<script>
testvar = "mytest";
</script>
<script src="index.js" type="module"/>
```

Since some html might not declare the testvar at all.
I try to make my script more robust by adding following in index.js:

```
testvar ??= "default";
```

However, this does not seem to work, it still raise `testvar is not defined` in latest chrome.

if I do:

```
let testvar;
testvar ??= "default";
```

It does not have error, but of course, the global testvar is not take into account this time. It will always be default.

I wonder, what is the correct way to do this, or there is no way to do things like this?

Comment: Note that self-closing `<script/>` tags do not work. Or at least, they *should* not work. A `<script>` even with a "src" should be `<script ...></script>`.

Comment: Modules make it intentionally hard to declare global variables. Does it actually *need* to be a global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `??=` to declare a global variable - you can only use it to set existing variables that are set to undefined.

You can instead do `globalThis.testvar ??= "default"`, which will work because you're setting a property rather than declaring a globally scoped variable.

This approach will still allow you to later access it as simply `testvar`.

```js
globalThis.testvar ??= "default"

console.log(testvar)
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis

Answer (score 0):

Top-level variables that are created in javascript (running in a browser) become properties of the `window` object.

That means you can access it everywhere with **`window.testvar`**.

You can also assign it with the `??=` operator.

Demo:

```js
// Here we can't use only `testvar` yet, it must be prefixed:
console.log(window.testvar ?? "-- HAS NO VALUE --");

window.testvar ??= "default";

// Now we can use it without the prefix:
console.log(testvar);
```